# How long does it take for a careers profile to show up in the search?

Tags: support, jobs

I have added a location in the "willing to relocate" field.

If I use the publicly available employer view to search for myself, I do not seem to be showing up. (I assume I should be a dot at my current location, Cologne).

How long does it take for a profile change to make it into the employer view?

> **Edit:** I am visible now, it just seems to have taken some time to work out. I'm leaving the question open anyway because this is surely going to come up again from someone else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search data is cached very heavily right now -- changes may not be reflected until up to 24 hours later.  This is because we are building big indexes in memory to do very fast searches, and there's no convenient way to update the indexes without rebuilding them from scratch.

The *profile itself* that the employer sees is always up-to-date with what you as a user see, since it's trivial to reload the profile from the DB on every view.  So if anyone looked at your profile, they would see "Willing to relocate to **X**" immediately after you added it.  However, because you weren't in the index until we rebuilt it several hours later, you wouldn't show up for searches in that location.

Comment: Good to know, thanks! Maybe this would be worth a small note somewhere in the interface ("Some changes may take up to 24 hours to show up" or something.)