# How do I get my careers page to show up in searches again?

Tags: support, jobs

A year ago I didn't have a software job and my careers page had almost nothing that would be appealing to employers. Now I've worked in the industry for a year and, a few days ago, I edited my profile to be much more appealing, such that I would expect it to show up in searches again and get some views.  Is there some way that I'm missing to indicate "Hey! My profile is completely different than it was 3 days ago!" or am I just stuck?

Answer (score 1):

Check your "privacy settings" (sidebar on top right of Careers) are

- Your profile is currently public.
- Your profile is currently being indexed and is searchable by search engines

And under *Employer Searches and Messaging* that it is not

- Block all messages and searches

You may also have to [wait about a day based on what index needs to be rebuilt](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/88921/how-long-does-it-take-for-a-careers-profile-to-show-up-in-the-search) that your profile would fall into.